# a List.iter that returns the list, in F#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
[ list of things ]
|> List.map    (fun i -> some transformation)    
|> List.iter   (fun i -> do stuff, like printfn or whatever)
|> List.filter (fun i -> ...)
|> List.andDoOtherThings... (fun i -> ...)
```

List.iter returns unit so this is not possible. But there are cases where I take a list, apply some filtering and transformations and then I need to do tasks based on that list (like with List.iter) and then carry on, doing other things with the same list. I can't do the iter as the last statement in this case.

I could write it as:

```
let myNewList =
    [ list of things ]
    |> List.map   (fun i -> some transformation)    

myNewList
|> List.iter  (fun i -> do stuff, like printfn or whatever)

myNewList
|> List.filter (fun i -> ...)
|> List.andDoOtherThings... (fun i -> ...)
```

but it's doing it all at once would be easier. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @tranquility suggests, I would probably just use a `List.map`, in which `do stuff, like printfn or whatever` is called before returning the input value.

But if this is a pattern you use frequently (e.g. for logging), you could define a Tee operator as seen in [linux](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) or [R](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/tee.html). This could look something like this

```
let tee func v =
    func(v) |> ignore
    v

[ list of things ]
|> List.map    (fun i -> some transformation)    
|> tee (List.iter (fun i -> do stuff, like printfn or whatever))
|> List.filter (fun i -> ...)
|> List.andDoOtherThings... (fun i -> ...)
```

In R this is implemented as an operator `%T>%`. This of course could be done in F# as well, though I would not recommend it. Generally I find that custom operators decrease readability.

Comment: I like this idea because it's still more readable than 'abusing' the Map. This is typically used for logging, so I think readability shouldn't be affected. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate further on torbondes answer, you could make an extension function like:

```
module List = 

    let doIter func lst = 
        lst |> List.iter func
        lst
```

so it can be piped nicely as:

```
[1..10]
|> List.map (fun x -> x * 2)
|> List.doIter (printfn "%d")
|> List.filter (fun x -> x % 4 = 0)
|> List.fold (fun sum x -> sum + x) 0
|> printfn "%d"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `List.map` again and just return the same value:

```
[ list of things ]
|> List.map    (fun i -> some transformation)    
|> List.map    
     (fun i -> 
          do stuff, like printfn or whatever
          i)
|> List.filter (fun i -> ...)
|> List.andDoOtherThings... (fun i -> ...)
```

With more than one map in series they can be combined to avoid an additional loop:

```
[ list of things ]
|> List.map    
     (fun i -> 
          let x = some transformation
          do stuff, like printfn or whatever
          x)
|> List.filter (fun i -> ...)
|> List.andDoOtherThings... (fun i -> ...)
```